# Android WebAuthn (FIDO) requireResidentKey

Tags: android, webauthn, fido

I would like to provide WebAuthn username-less login experience with [The requireResidentKey](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#ref-for-resident-credential%E2%91%A1) and [resident-credential](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#resident-credential) defined in the WebAuthn Spec

However, When preparing the AuthenticatorSelectionCriteria [AuthenticatorSelectionCriteria](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fido/fido2/api/common/AuthenticatorSelectionCriteria) for registration using the [Builder](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fido/fido2/api/common/AuthenticatorSelectionCriteria.Builder), the builder does not allow to set the requireResidentKey and userVerification. Is there a reason why Google hides those interfaces?

Comment: Probably not implemented yet as the internal platform authenticator does not support resident keys and additionally the user always have to interact with the UI.

Comment: are there plans to support resident keys on the internal authenticator? fyi ios 14 does seem to support it

Comment: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/fido2-codelab/issues/12 I think they are planning to, but cannot confirm the schedule.